# Eclipse thinks my project is an Android project - can I remove without starting over?

Tags: android, eclipse, project-settings

I created a project, probably as an Android project without thinking.  I then did a lot of work bringing in source, etc. but it is not an Android target.  However, when I start up Eclipse, it keeps popping-up a dialog reminding me that I have not established the Adroid device settings.  How can I make it stop -- without restarting the workspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to remove android-specific stuff from `.classpath` & `.project` files that are in the root of the project folder, namely

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>

<buildCommand>
    <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</name>
    <arguments>
    </arguments>
</buildCommand>

<nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
```

Comment: Perfect.  I found the settings but I will do the surgery this weekend.

Comment: I was finally able to make this work.  I took a good project and diff'ed .project and .classpath until I got the edits correct.  Then it worked!  BTW - I have also used it in the reverse fashion to import an Android project out of source control that did not check-in .project or .classpath.  I was able to fix-up my project to become an Android project.

Answer (score 2):

Alex's answer works perfectly. 
One extra piece of info:

I was initially a building [Android send-me-logs](http://code.google.com/p/android-send-me-logs/source/checkout). It requires android libraries. So I initially used the Eclipse wizard to "convert to android project". Then it started asking me about Android manifests and things like that so I realised I shouldn't have.

So I stripped out the Android *nature* as per Alex's answer (close down Eclipse first just to be safe) but then I still had the "AndroidManifest.xml missing" error which wouldn't go away when cleaning the project.

So instead I right clicked on the error, deleted it and problem was solved. If only all errors could be dealt with like this!

Comment: Thats a neat add ... agree, where else can we just delete errors and make them go away :)  If I can delete a compiler error and have Eclipse fix my code.